# DOM event attributeModified/attributeRemoved/characterDataModified... are not triggered

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, mutation-observers, mutation-events

After
`chrome.debugger.sendCommand({tabId:tabId}, "DOM.enable")`, I found only event `DOM.documentUpdated` can be triggered, but others:

```
    DOM.attributeModified
    DOM.attributeRemoved
    DOM.characterDataModified
    DOM.childNodeCountUpdated
    DOM.childNodeInserted
    DOM.childNodeRemoved
```

can not be triggered. I think I should miss some calls to set something like MutationObserver options:

```
{
  boolean childList = false;
  boolean attributes;
  boolean characterData;
  boolean subtree = false;
  boolean attributeOldValue;
  boolean characterDataOldValue;
  sequence<DOMString> attributeFilter;
}
```

Any other chrome.debugger command I need to call for this?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem. Was hoping to find out why. I wonder if these are being deprecated and no one told us.

Comment: since I had the same problem - I created an issue on bugs.chromium.org on this problem, maybe something will be answered, or maybe not:https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1342591