# DevTools - DOM domain - only one event

Tags: chromium, chrome-devtools-protocol

I'm trying to use DevTools protocol - for DOM domain [events:https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/DOM/](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/DOM/)

I activate the DOM domain, it is successfully activated.

Now I get events, BUT when loading the URL - I always get only one event: *DOM.documentUpdated*

Other events such as:

```
DOM.attributeModified
DOM.attributeRemoved
DOM.characterDataModified
DOM.childNodeCountUpdated
DOM.childNodeInserted
DOM.childNodeRemoved
DOM.documentUpdated
DOM.setChildNodes
```

they never come. Is this how it should be ?

.
.
.

I found a similar problem: [DOM event attributeModified/attributeRemoved/characterDataModified... are not triggered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65051934/dom-event-attributemodified-attributeremoved-characterdatamodified-are-not-tr)

Apparently the DOM-domain for Chrome DevTools protocol - is not working correctly.

Answer (score 1):

A funny thing about the DOM domain is that the node events are only sent regarding nodes that are in the frontend. Nodes are in the backend by default.

A simple call to `DOM.getDocument` with `depth` set to `-1` and `pierce` set to `true` will push all the nodes to the frontend. Please note that pierce is relevant for sub-documents (such as iframes) and is not necessary in many occasions.

All changes to frontend nodes will be reported to you via the events you mentioned.